# HTML: Can't make URL in table cell fit the way I want

Tags: html, css, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to display a URL in a table cell, in a Firefox Jetpack SDK addon Panel. I've tried to achieve mainly 2 different layouts, and neither worked. I've used various threads here on SO to try and find a solution, but I want to keep this clean (no JS tricks or external libraries), don't want to specify exact sizes, and half the answers on those threads confused me or did not work because my case is slightly different. CSS itself is also confusing as hell to me because of how unintuitive it is, so needless to say my attempts have probably been all but efficient. A Jetpack Panel also seems to behave in strange ways regarding sizing, so that adds to the complexity.

**Panel content**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="status">Status</th>
                <th class="message">Message</th>
                <th class="url">URL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="entries">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Adding a td row**

```
const table = document.getElementById("entries");
function entry(data) {
let tr = document.createElement("tr");
for (let i in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        let td = document.createElement("td");
        if (i == "url") {
            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = data[i];
            a.textContent = data[i];
            a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
            td.appendChild(a);
        } else {
            td.textContent = data[i];
        }
        td.setAttribute("class", i);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

TL:DR add a td for status and message, and use an anchor tag inside the final td to display url.

**Attempted CSS**

```
table {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
td.url a {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Desired outcomes**

I don't want to ever see a horizontal scrollbar appear! The panel itself is supposed to be auto-sized (by Firefox), displaying the table inside it at an unknown size that supposedly fits the user's device. The table should fill up the panel's width without exceeding it and causing horizontal overflow.

The url should be displayed in a single line, cut off with an ellipsis when it reaches the td's maximum width (which is implicit, coming from the table's max size minus the minimum width to display the other tds).

I do not want to specify exact widths or anything of the sort, to preserve responsive design and user-preferences like default font and fontsize.

TL:DR what I want to achieve is a table with natural sizing, 2 columns that are displayed naturally and 1 column that is cut off when it exceeds the implicit remaining size.

The current outcome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGF3u.png (what happened to table's max-size?)

A previous attempt, when I wanted the url to be displayed in exactly 2 lines of plain text, cut off with an ellipsis: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRb7a.png (that's right, it did *nothing*)

Thanks to anyone who can help me get to a working solution with this, I'm personally starting to drown in CSS statements that make no sense to me anymore.

> It's 2015 and CSS is still so awfully clunky we still can't achieve basic crap like this without hours of messing around with things that often don't seem relevant, like position declarations? How is CSS fulfilling its purpose as a presentation technology if basic presentations are still as complicated as writing a lazy-loaded database in Haskell? http://img.pandawhale.com/post-18529-Peter-Griffin-blinds-CSS-gif-I-lEO1.gif

Comment: I just read text-overflow doesn't work on inline elements - does it work if you give the td.url or td.url a {display: inline-block} ?

Comment: @wunth neither works

Comment: Apparently an overflow property is needed as well (hidden, scroll or auto) https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

Comment: @wunth still no dice: http://i.imgur.com/Tjek9VF.png same visual result as before, td width is increased and horizontal scrollbar appears

Comment: There's still a minor scroll but that might be easy to troubleshoot - I have to head off sorry so best of luck - hope this gets you closer http://jsfiddle.net/1vjvxwzo/

Comment: @wunth using that fiddle means specifying sizes, which I want to avoid: http://i.imgur.com/9vvwtoo.png I want the left columns to scale to their content naturally, and the url column to fill up whatever's left within the table's natural size.

Comment: A spoiler tag, seriously?

Comment: @lister because that paragraph technically isn't part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the results of more tinkering and tidbits of info from other posts, text-overflow only works if

- the element has display: block
- the element has a width in px

So unless I've gone insane/retarded, this pretty much means that there is no such thing as using CSS to make a page both presentable and responsive, because apparently half of the basic presentation tricks still require crap like setting a width in px, undoing responsiveness.

Anyone with me to sign this petition to get whoever draws up the CSS specs fired? 3rd iteration and it still utterfy fails to deliver what it promises.

Comment: CSS is a language, which, like all languages, can be difficult to learn. You can't just jump in and use it; just like a foreign language, you shouldn't expect that a dictionary is all you need. It takes practice, you may need to take tutorials, to search many websites, to practice some more, until you not just know the intricacies, you _understand_ the intricacies. Only then will you be authorised to say that you don't like it and that the whole CSS project should be scrapped because you can do better.

Comment: I've been at it for 7 years. JS/CSS mods for a simple HTML game is what I started out doing. I never stopped using it as I make websites and Firefox addons among other things. It's not like I only started working with CSS yesterday. It's just that after all this time and watching so many people raise issues with CSS, it baffles me that it's still such a difficult tool to use despite its monopoly on its purpose.

Comment: Now you're making it sound even more like a rant than like an actual question. So do you want your problem solved, or did you just feel the need to vent?

Comment: No, the problem's been taken care of and like I said in my own answer, it's clear I either have to set absolute sizes or live with lacking display features, by design. I ditched the entire UI widget, it was redundant anyway.

Comment: Aw, and I had my answer all ready, which did exactly what you asked. Shame.